# Combinatorics problem that deals with trigonometric functions

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry, summation, exponentiation

> If $m$ and $p$ are positive integers and $m \geq p$, then show that
>   $${m \choose 0}+{m \choose p}+{m \choose 2p}+{m \choose 3p}+\cdots$$
>   has value $${2^m \over p}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\left \lfloor {p-1 \over 2} \right \rfloor}{{\left( \cos{k\pi \over p}\right)}^m \cos{mk\pi \over p}}\right)$$

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I cannot find a way to express combinatorial arguments using trigonometric functions. It'd be great if someone can give me any hints.

Comment: I would try looking at something like $$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}(1+\zeta^i)^m$$ where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}$.

Comment: You can use `\left` and `\right` with `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` to make them adapt to their content.

Comment: @joriki Thanks. Corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $\zeta=e^{2\pi\mathrm i/p}$ as Gerry suggested,

\begin{align}
\sum_{l=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac mp\right\rfloor}\binom m{lp}
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom mj\frac1p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{jk}\\
&=\frac1p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\sum_{j=0}^m\binom mj\zeta^{jk}\\
&=\frac1p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\left(1+\xi^k\right)^m\\
&=\frac{2^m}p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\left(\cos\frac{k\pi}p\right)^m\mathrm e^{mk\pi\mathrm i/p}\\
&=\frac{2^m}p\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{p-1}2\right\rfloor}\left(\cos\frac{k\pi}p\right)^m\cos\frac{mk\pi}p\right)\;,
\end{align}

so I think you were missing a factor of $2$ before the sum.

Comment: I cannot understand the very first line.

Comment: I think the upper limit of the second sum on the first line should be $p-1$.

Comment: @SayantanSantra: Sorry, yes -- all those upper limits were supposed to be $p-1$. Fixed. Does that resolve your question about the first line?

Comment: Yeah. Now it's clear. Thanks for this briliant answer.

Comment: @SayantanSantra: The $1$ is the $k=0$ term. It's the only one that doesn't form a pair. Note that if $p$ is even, the $k=\frac p2$ term also isn't paired, but in this case $\cos\frac{k\pi}m=\cos\frac\pi2=0$.

Comment: Yeah. Got that.

Comment: Just FYI, [it's probably not an old contest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808913/shortest-path-in-a-weighted-graph-with-coloured-edges). But I didn't find a source.